# Images automatically fitted to screen in portrait and landscape on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, image, web-applications, css, aspect-ratio

I need to adjust images to the screen size on the iPhone in portrait and landscape.
The images are loaded dynamically and in different ratios.

I want to accomplish that the images have a maximal size inside the screen. 
The problem is that some of them need to have a width of 100% and others need to have a height of 100% depending on their ratio.

Previously I have done that with JavaScript and individually resized those images when they were loaded or the screen was rotated but I was hoping for a css only solution so my webApp won't so heavy in JavaScript.

Anybody know a solution?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to use CSS to limit the size of the images. For example:

```
<img src="someimage.jpg" style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at ***contentMode*** property of UIImageView. You could choose to use ***UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill*** if that suits your purpose.

Comment: I am developing a web app using html css3 and javascript. Isn't UIImageView a class of the iPhone SDK so only for native apps?

Comment: True, it was not clear in your question if you are looking for web-app and not native apps. It might be worthwhile editing your question so that you get the correct response. All the best!

Comment: I should've made that more clear. Thank you for your help anyway.